# I have an enormus .tab (notepad) files, which i want to Merge into one;

Tags: text-processing

I have .tab files, which have for example : 3 columns,  and , lets say 100 lines.

I want to merge them and have, for 2 .tab files , 3 columns  and  have 200 lines.

Is there a way to do it for 100+ files?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Would this command help you?

```
cat *.tab > merged.tab
```

Comment: No, that will not work.

Comment: See http://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/34291/merging-multiple-tab-files

Comment: @bodhi.zazen why is that relevant? This should work perfectly well. You will get a warning about input file being the output file and If there are too many files, you'll hit ARG_MAX, but it should work for simple cases. These aren't MapInfo .tab binary files, the OP states they are simple text with 3 columns.